# How to say pacman that package is already updated?

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

For example I have Intellij Idea installed on my Arch Linux system. Intellij Idea has built in updater and assume that I's already updated Intellij Idea with that built in Intellij Idea updater. But when I perform "yaourt -Syu" corresponding Intellij Idea's package is still shown in list of packages that are waiting for updates. So how can I say yaourt or pacman (or any other pacman wrapper that may have such feature) that package is already updated?

Comment: You can also try `yaourt -Syua`... or ‘-a’ update AUR packages, so resync, update, include aur is `yaourt -Syyua`

Comment: I would be happy if ignoring specific version would be possible but even such feature seems not to be realized (

Answer (score 0):

If you just want that Feature I would recommend `yay` to you, it has that Feature to skip an installation of a Packet! As discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4azqyb/whats_so_bad_with_yaourt/) you shouldn't use `yaourt` anymore.

If you don't want that update Problem at all install [jetbrains-toolbox](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jetbrains-toolbox/) which will manage your installed IDEs, if you are using more than one, so you only have to update the toolbox once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't updated it. You've overwritten the copy pacman knows about, with an untracked copy from elsewhere.

So, of course, pacman's metadata will not be updated. In order to circumvent this you'd need to create a custom dummy package which provides intellij, while managing it entirely yourself.

But what is wrong with using the official repository package https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=intellij-idea-community-edition and just letting pacman update it for you?

Comment: Intellijs own updates are only partial updates. The arch package always installs the whole package again.